# p:commandButton not invoking action

Tags: jsf, primefaces, action

I've got a p:commandButton in a simple login form. The action is not firing. I've verified that the controller and function exist, checked for nested f:forms, enclosed everything in f:view, removed validation requirements, but the action doesn't fire.

The action listener just sets the login flag and then the page refreshes with new rendering. If I reference the listener function directly, it fires, but not from the commandButton.

Here's the controller bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "uiController")
@SessionScoped
public class UiController implements Serializable {

private Boolean isLoggedIn;
private String userName;
private String password;

public UiController() {
    isLoggedIn = false;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Boolean getIsLoggedIn() {
    return isLoggedIn;
}

public String getLoginLogoTopLine() {
    return "Yoyodyne";
}

public String getLoginLogoBottomLine() {
    return "Corporation";
}

public void login() {
    isLoggedIn = true;
}

}
```

Here's the html:

```
    <h:head>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="jsfcrud.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="transend-ui.css"/>
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="jsfcrud.js"/>
</h:head>
<h:body id="enchilada">
    <f:view>
        <p:growl id="growl" life="3000" />
        <h:panelGroup id="loginContainer" styleClass="ts-page-container ts-login-container" rendered="#{!uiController.isLoggedIn}">
            <h:panelGroup styleClass="ts-northwest-container">
                <h:outputText value="#{uiController.loginLogoTopLine}" styleClass="ts-login-logo-top" />
                <h:outputText value="#{uiController.loginLogoBottomLine}" styleClass="ts-login-logo-bottom" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup styleClass="ts-centered-container">

                <h:form id="LoginForm">
                    <h:inputHidden value="#{shipperCode}" />
                    <p:panelGrid styleClass="ts-login-panel">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column styleClass="">
                                <p:panelGrid styleClass="">
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:outputLabel styleClass="ts-login-prompt" value="#{bundle.LoginLabel_userName}" for="userName" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputText value="#{uiController.userName}" id="userName" title="#{bundle.LoginTitle_userName}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                    <p:row>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:outputLabel styleClass="ts-login-prompt" value="#{bundle.LoginLabel_password}" for="password" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column>
                                            <p:inputText value="#{uiController.password}" id="password" title="#{bundle.LoginTitle_password}"/>
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:row>
                                </p:panelGrid> 

                            </p:column>
                            <p:column>
                                <p:commandButton action="#{uiController.login}" value="login" oncomplete="window.location.replace(window.location.href);"/>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </p:panelGrid>
                </h:form>
                <h:messages />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="mainContainer" styleClass="ts-page-container ts-main-container" rendered="#{uiController.isLoggedIn}">
        </h:panelGroup>
    </f:view>
</h:body>
```

UPDATE

OK sorry for posting snippets in the comments. I usually work things out for myself. This is the first time I've had to ask for help and I'm not familiar with posting. Not a newb at Java, definitely a newb at this.

Here's what I now have for html:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body id="enchilada">
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="LoginForm">
                <p:commandButton action="#{uiController.login}" value="login"/>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>

</html>
```

Here's the bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "uiController")
  @SessionScoped
  public class UiController implements Serializable {

    public void login() {
        System.out.println("login invoked");
    }
}
```

Comment: People want an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For such a simple example, I expect to see that you've tested a single command button in a single form with a single backing-bean with a single method. If you can't re-create the problem in the simple example, then gradually add your changes until you can, and chances are, you'll have answered your own question.

Comment: I've got commandButtons working in many other places. This is pretty simple. I've stripped everything else out besides two fields and a single action method. There is a single commandButton in a single form. The backing bean is only getters/setters and the login function. There's something I'm missing.

Comment: If you've stripped "everything else out" and it's still not working, then you haven't stripped enough out. _Something_ is causing the failure. You should be able to isolate it to "if I do this one thing, it fails."

Comment: Here is the html stripped to nothing:
    <h:body id="enchilada">
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="LoginForm">
                <p:commandButton action="#{uiController.login}" value="login" oncomplete="window.location.replace(window.location.href);"/>
            </h:form>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>`

Comment: Obviously something is causing the failure. I'm not a newb. I've figured my way through things much more complex than this, but there is something I'm missing here. Are you going to maybe help me or just keep telling me I've got a problem?

Comment: FWIW, this is the very first time I've ever posted a question here. On the other hand, I've searched for and found answers here thousands of times.

Comment: To illustrate the MCVE importance, with the code posted so far you're basically implying that the problem disappears once you remove e.g. `styleClass="ts-login-panel"`. This is not true. This part (and many other parts) thus only introduces noise in the question, distracting experts from spotting the problem by just glancing over the minimum code snippet.

Comment: What do you mean? I've been trying to help the whole time :-\ I haven't even downvoted your question. I'm trying to reproduce your issue with your code snippet right now.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code snippet you posted in your comment, Loki. I created a session-scoped backing-bean with a single method, `login`, but the method is called when I click the button.

Comment: I haven't been able to make the problem go away no matter what I strip out. I didn't intentionally remove the styleClass, probably lost it in an edit.

Comment: Have you stripped out `jsfcrud.js`? What is that, anyhow?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format or add code snippets in replies. I've stripped it down to nothing but the form, only one method in the bean. jsfcrud is primefaces. I've removed it too.

Comment: Technically we shouldn't be doing this in the comments. You should update your question with an MCVE: the absolute bare minimum code that reproduces the problem. Someone (e.g. me) should be able to copy-paste your code and run it without hardly any modification.

Comment: I updated the question. Then realized I had re-added the jfscrud so deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a problem with your namespace declarations. You have used:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Replace the above with:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

To be honest, I'm not familiar with how these namespace declarations work, so I don't know if or why this would make a difference. I would have put this in a comment, but it's too long.

Comment: Made no difference. I'll just have to step away from this for a while then do it over.

Comment: That's odd. It does make a difference for me, but, like I said, I'm not really sure how namespaces work, so I guess I shouldn't be surprised it didn't solve your problem. I'll leave my answer here for evidence.

Comment: @LokiSmokes: "... step away from this for a while then do it over." That's a good idea, but just to emphasize that's basically how you create an MCVE: you start from scratch and reproduce the problem.